# Generate Options with Optgroups using map and ES6 arrow functions

Tags: json, dictionary, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm working in React and I have the following data-structure from which I'm trying to produce the options for a select drop-down component, including OptGroups to bucket the three sets of team-members using map and ES6 arrow-functions.

```
    "teams": [
    {
        "Group A": 
            [
                { "id": "A1", "name": "John" },
                { "id": "A2", "name": "Erin" },
                { "id": "A3", "name": "Steve" }
            ],
        "Group B":
            [
                { "id": "B1", "name": "Mark" },
                { "id": "B2", "name": "Doug" },
                { "id": "B3", "name": "Sam" },
                { "id": "B4", "name": "Kate" }
            ],
        "Group C":
            [
                { "id": "C1", "name": "Michelle" },
                { "id": "C2", "name": "April" },
                { "id": "C3", "name": "Mike" },
                { "id": "C4", "name": "Albert" }
            ]
    }
]
```

Before the JSON was nested with the team-grouping, I had been using this syntax:

```
let teamOptions = this.props.firm.teams.map(memb => <Option key={memb.id}>{memb.name}</Option>);
```

Now that I've nested the team-members into groups, I haven't been able to figure out the correct way to process this.

I'd like the output to resemble:

```
<OptGroup label="Group A">
    <Option value="A1">John</Option>
    <Option value="A2">Erin</Option>
    <Option value="A3">Erin</Option>
</OptGroup>
<OptGroup label="Group B">
    <Option value="B1">Mark</Option>
    <Option value="B2">Doug</Option>
    <Option value="B3">Sam</Option>
    <Option value="B4">Kate</Option>
</OptGroup>
<OptGroup label="Group C">
    <Option value="C1">Michelle</Option>
    <Option value="C2">April</Option>
    <Option value="C3">Mike</Option>
    <Option value="C4">Albert</Option>
</OptGroup>
```

Comment: Just curious, shouldn't those tag names be lowercase?

Comment: Why is `teams` an array that contains one object?

Comment: @Bergi In React, components are usually written with a capital letter.

Comment: @Ksyqo I thought that's for *components* only (custom or builtin *classes* with capitalised constructor names, the usual convention), not for raw HTML tags.

Comment: @Bergi Oh yeah, you're right. But is it case sensitive though ?

Comment: @Ksyqo Apparently not as now I have seen both casings work, I just thought the convention would be lowercase tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bergi mentions, its a little unclear if the structure that you provide in your example array has one object, as opposed to a format like this:

```
"teams": [
  {
    "name": "Group A",
    "players": [
      { "id": "A1", "name": "John" },
      { "id": "A2", "name": "Erin" },
      { "id": "A3", "name": "Steve" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Group B",
    "players": [
      { "id": "B1", "name": "Mark" },
      { "id": "B2", "name": "Doug" },
      { "id": "B3", "name": "Sam" },
      { "id": "B4", "name": "Kate" }
    ]
  },
]
```

but regardless, to answer your question on how to map over it, I would do so like this: note that your array has one object so I am grabbing the first item in your teams array and then iterating over the keys/values. Given that you want to iterated over the first object, this is how I would do it:

```
const keys = Object.keys(this.props.firm.teams[0]);
const values = Object.values(this.props.firm.teams[0]);

const teamOptions = values.map((group, i) => {
  <OptGroup label={keys[i]} />
    { group.map(player => <Option value={player.id}>{player.name}</Option>) }
  </OptGroup>
});
```

Comment: You might want to use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to loop over keys and values together.

Comment: Good point, but I believe Object.entries is only supported by es2017 at the moment, is that correct?

Comment: It's in the ES2017 standard, yes, but browsers already support it (and older ones need a polyfill - just as usual)